# Stop Ghostscript from replacing embedded fonts?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Using Ghostscript 9.19, Windows 10 Pro

I am using Ghostscript to convert an existing PDF to PDF/A-1b.

However, even though the required fonts are already embedded in my original PDF,
Ghostscript is substituting them in the output PDF/A file.

Specifically:
Substituting font Times-Bold for Times New Roman,Bold.
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Substituting font Times-Italic for Times New Roman,Italic.

I have Times New Roman installed on my machine (it's there by default).

Here's my command line:

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin>gswin64c -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE 
 -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
 -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sFontPath=C:/Windows/Fonts 
  -IC:/windows/fonts -sOutputFile=C:/temp/testerA.pdf c:/temp/tester.pdf
```

BEFORE processing with Gjostscript:
[image]

AFTER processing with Ghostscript:
[image]

Why is Ghostscript substituting an embedded font?

How can I prevent Ghostscript from substituting embedded fonts?

EDIT: Screenshot of the Times font from my system showing that the name matches the embedded name in the PDF:

[image]

Comment: Hm, as a start I would remove these options `-sFontPath=C:/Windows/Fonts   -IC:/windows/fonts ` if all fonts are already included in the pdf, and maybe add `-dNOPLATFONTS`

Comment: I had originally converted without the font paths in the command line and still saw the same substitution. I added the paths later in an effort to resolve it, but substitution continues....

Answer (score 2):

Well the basic answer here is simply that the fonts are **not** embedded in the first place.

Looking at the original font list we see:

```
Times New Roman
Actual Font: TimesNewRomanPSMT
```

Which is not the same font. Similarly Times New Roman,Italic is not the same font as TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT etc.

Having TimesNewRomanPSMT on your machine, and having -sFontPath set to point to that directory, means that should you have input which uses a font called 'TimesNewRomanPSMT' but does not embed it, then Ghostscript will use the TrueType font from disk, because it has the same name.

"Times New Roman" is not the same name as "TimesNewRomanPSMT", so Ghostscript won't use TimesNewRomanPSMT as a replacement for Time New Roman, instead it uses its built in fonts and decides the closest match it has to Times New Roman is Times, which seems entirely reasonable to me.

You *can* define substitutions yourself, so if you want to use TimesNewRomanPSMT as a substitute for Times New Roman, you can do so. You just need to edit fontmap.GS.

But fundamentally Ghostscript is not replacing embedded fonts, because the fonts are not embedded. Note that its a requirement of PDF/A that all fonts be embedded, so the pdfwrite device isn't even able to leave the fonts non-embedded as they are, it **must** embed something.

Comment: What you say seems reasonable, however I looked into the Times font on my Windows 10 system and the font is actually named TimesNewRomanPSMT - I've added a new image to my original post. In other words, the font IS embedded in the original PDF.

Comment: No the font isn't embedded. The font requested by the PDF file is called "Times New Roman" Acrobat can't find a font by that name in the PDF file, or on disk, so it chooses to use the available font called "TimesNewRomanPSMT" instead. That's why Acrobat tells you: "Actual Font TimesNewRomanPSMT". Looking at the name of the replacement font won't tell you anything, if you want to know what's in the PDF file, you have to look inside the PDF file, or use a tool which can do it for you. Take my word for it, the font is not embedded.